# Strange behavior in AMD64 Instruction pointer

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

I was reading Hacking: The Art of Exploitation by Jon Erickson, and followed the example in the book in my Kali Linux system (64 bit).

I wrote a simple C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       printf("Hello");
    }
}
```

After using objdump and gdb to examine the executable, I found something strange.

[image: Screenshot]

As the picture shows, the main function was in the "0x000000000000063a".

But the breakpoint info after the gdb "run" command, it seems that the program stopped at 63e rather than 63a.

Another peculiar thing is that the value in the instruction pointer (rip) was 0x55555555463e. 
Shouldn't it be 0x000000000000063a?
Where do those `5`s come from?

Comment: The code is [**relocated**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)), that's where the `0x0x55555555463e` comes from.

Comment: Also in gdb disassemble the code at `55555555463e` and you'll see (not sure which is the appropriate command in gdb for disassembling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB sets breakpoints on useful code for a function if you don't set an asterisk. It omits all preparation for a function(prologue). To make it clear try to debug the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=10;
    i++;
    return 0;
}
```

Gdb session:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483e1
(gdb) b *main
Breakpoint 2 at 0x80483db
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/src/main 

Breakpoint 2, 0x080483db in main ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
=> 0x080483db <+0>: push   ebp
   0x080483dc <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483de <+3>: sub    esp,0x10
   0x080483e1 <+6>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0xa
   0x080483e8 <+13>:    add    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x1
   0x080483ec <+17>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x080483f1 <+22>:    leave  
   0x080483f2 <+23>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x080483e1 in main ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080483db <+0>: push   ebp
   0x080483dc <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483de <+3>: sub    esp,0x10
=> 0x080483e1 <+6>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0xa
   0x080483e8 <+13>:    add    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x1
   0x080483ec <+17>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x080483f1 <+22>:    leave  
   0x080483f2 <+23>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

in this case, preparation to execute useful code of the function is  :

```
0x080483db <+0>: push   ebp
0x080483dc <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
0x080483de <+3>: sub    esp,0x10
```

first instruction in `main`:

```
int i=10;
```

compiled into:

```
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0xa
```

GDB set a breakpoint on the instruction, when we give the command `b main`

But if we use the command with an asterisk(pointer) `b *main` we set a breakpoint on the actual address of the function(on first instruction of  prologue).

In OP case, if we set breakpoint by `break *main` and then `run`, the instruction pointer register(`rip`) will have the value `0x55555555463a`

Comment: It's ambiguous what you mean by "Nothing changes if you use 64-bit".  That sentence might mean "the 64-bit version of `main` does all that crap to align the stack just like 32-bit".  That's not what you mean (I hope), so you should say "64-bit takes advantage of the ABI guarantee that RSP is aligned on entry so it doesn't include gcc's funky stack-alignment code that copies the stack frame".  (The 32-bit ABI changed more recently to guaranteeing 16-byte alignment, and gcc doesn't assume it on entry to main in 32-bit mode).

Comment: @PeterCordes: When I say nothing changes for 64-bit, I mean that a standard function entry sequence exists in 64-bit and gdb behaves the same.

Comment: That's what I thought, so your answer should say so.  If readers don't already know the details, there is ambiguity in your answer as written.

Comment: You seem to be completely missing the point.  Of course GDB behaves the same, the ambiguity is whether 64-bit `main` is the same as 64-bit  `testFunc`, or whether 64-bit `main` is the same as 32-bit `main` (and thus *different* from 64-bit `testFunc`).  And this isn't GDB behaviour, it's GCC code-gen behaviour.  (The special stack-alignment stuff in 32-bit `main` is emitted even with -O3  https://godbolt.org/g/dzUjS1.  Or in any function which needs more than 16-byte alignment in 32 or 64-bit mode, e.g. with `__m256` locals that it needs to spill.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: OP `But the breakpoint info after the gdb "run" command, it seems that the program stopped at 63e rather than 63a.` There is no `gcc`. What would be if the program is not compiled `gcc`?

Comment: If the program was compiled with `clang` instead of `gcc`, it's `main` wouldn't be "special" and would have the same prologue as `testFunc`.

Comment: Or just look at the godbolt link in my previous comment, and flip the compiler over to clang in the dropdown.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for corrections, I changed all to be clearly. Any corrections else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165661/discussion-between-tigertv-ru-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that `*main` is the GDB syntax for setting a breakpoint at a specific address, instead of on a function name.  `main` in `*main` is treated as a function pointer, so you get the actual function pointer value to the first instruction of the prologue, instead of to code for the first source line in the function.

Comment: @PeterCordes: added